# Configure IIS Web Farm Servers

Tags: linux, iis, windows-update, web-farm-framework

I'm trying to configure IIS Web Farm Servers referring to the following link.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj129399(v=ws.11).aspx

I've been following the steps and have got the server of shared content connected by two IIS servers as redundancy. Thanks for the redundancy now the **Windows Update** on IIS server doesn't bother any more but the **Windows Update** on the server with shared content still make a down time on the system.

My question is, can I use Linux as the server of shared content, to minimize the frequent down time made by Microsoft Windows Update?

On top of my head there could be an issue when establishing connection between servers, while domain credentials can't be applied. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The single file server can be replaced by an active passive file server cluster.

Comment: @LexLi can you kindly give me a hint on the starting point I should look at? I've googled and found heaps of unrelated links - probably not suit my need.

Comment: learn how to limit your search to TechNet.Microsoft.com